# The collection.find function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm programming a discord bot with **discord.js** library and when I try the following method

```
collection.find(async x => x.name === 'test')
```

it doesn't work but there's also no error.
What can I do about this?

Comment: If you wrote literally `collection.find(async function)`, it is impossible that there is no error, because that is not grammatical JavaScript. If you are using `async function` as a metasyntactic variable, i.e. there is something there but you "summarised" it, we can't debug it because there is not enough details to say anything about it with confidence (but if the function is indeed `async`, it can't work because you would be looking for a promise, which is not in the collection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide proper function for it to work.

I think, You are kind of providing empty function so no error, also no working as function body is empty.

Here is example `collection.find(u => u.discriminator === '1000');`

Resource https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods

Comment: Well, I used the function like this:
```
collection.find(async x => x.name == 'test')
```
And it doesn't work with no error.

Comment: Well, this should have worked, if some `name` is equals to `test`. However your syntax seems OK.
By the way why are you using `async` in this scenario as you are not using `await`. Have you tried without `async`?

Comment: Aha! I just tried without `async` and that works!